# JavaScript wait for async functions in while loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, while-loop, promise

I currently have 5 functions; each one uses `setInterval` to wait for an element to load and than clicks the element when it is available which leads to the next webpage. These functions also take place inside of a `while` loop. It is very important that these functions take place one after another and the `while` loop waits for all the functions to complete before looping again. Due to the functions being asynchronous the loop will run `x` times before any of the functions can even load.

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
function one () {
    var checkForItem = setInterval(function () {
        if ($('#element').length) {
            $('#element').click();
            clearInterval(checkForItem);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Imagine 5 of these functions (`one`, `two`, `three`, `four`, `five`), all with the same format using `setInterval` and the following `while` loop:

```
var x = 0, y = 10;

while (x < y){
    one();
    two();
    three();
    four();
    five();
    x++
}
```

How would I go about ensuring all the functions take place one after another before having the loop continue?

Note: I have tried using promises although due to the functions being async the loop still continues before the functions complete.

Comment: Indenting your code properly would make it a lot more readable.

Comment: What is the reason for executing the loop if it's not modifying the function's behavior? by executing those functions once will work

Comment: @JoseAPL The functions will act differently as x increases. The above is just a simple example of what I am trying to do. The functions will click different buttons and scrape some content based on an array and the x value.

Comment: Each one of your functions needs to return a promise so you can wait for all the calls using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) Alternatively, you can use https://github.com/angular/zone.js/ which does track asynchronous JS code by patching low level calls like `setTimeout`

Comment: `each one uses setInterval to wait for an element to load` - sounds hackish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `async`/`await` syntax with the promises:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}
async function one() {
    while (!$('#element').length) {
        await delay(100);
    }
    $('#element').click();
}

async function main() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        await one();
        await two();
        await three();
        await four();
        await five();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the selectors in an array, and gradually iterate over the array in the interval, until the end of the array is reached:

```
const initialSelectorsToFind = ['#element1', '#element2', '#element3']; // add more as desired
const elementSelectorsToFind = Array.from({ length: 10 })
  .reduce(arrSoFar => [...arrSoFar, ...initialSelectorsToFind], []);
let elementIndexToFind = 0;
function tryClick(){
  const elementToFind = $(elementSelectorsToFind[elementIndexToFind]);
  if (elementToFind.length) {
    elementToFind.click();
    elementIndexToFind++;
    if (elementIndexToFind === elementSelectorsToFind.length) {
      clearInterval(tryClickInterval);
    }
  }
}
const tryClickInterval = setInterval(tryClick, 100);
```

But if you're trying to trigger a function (such as something that clicks an element) when an element gets added to the DOM, it would be far better off to use something that triggers *when* the add occurs, such as a callback in the creator function, or MutationObserver

Comment: First off, I want to thank you as you also helped me last night! This solution won't work for me as I essentially need `elementSelectorsToFind` to be traversed `x` times, hence the need of a loop.

Comment: See edit: you can use `.reduce` at first to repeat the initial selectors any number of times

Answer (score -1):

Try wrap  promise with async await:

```
async function one (){
      await (new Promise(function(reolve, reject){
         var checkForItem = setInterval(function () {
           if ($('#element').length) {
              $('#element').click();
              clearInterval(checkForItem);
              resolve();
            }
         }, 100);
      }));
}

//And then in your while loop:
while (x < y){
    await one();
    await two();
    ...
    x++
}
```

***note***: your while loop must be wrapped in an async function also.

Comment: what's with the *do nothing* `.then()` ? Also, and it's not clear in your code **at all**, `await one()` etc must be performed in an `async` function